# Generate WCF JSON format Date with moment.js or another javascript library

Tags: javascript, json, wcf, momentjs, date-formatting

I am consuming a WCF Service in Javascript and need to play around with dates.

I was looking around for some nice DateTime handlers for the format the DataContractJsonSerializer generates { "date": "/Date(1260597600000-0600)/" } and found moment.js. moment.js is really excellent to consume this date format, handles the format including the timezone.

What I need now is generate the WCF date format from a Javascript or moment Date to send dates with timezones in the request on my POST method and looking in the documentation of moment.js couldn't find anything that has the output I need.

Any idea how to achieve this with moment.js or any other js library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With moment.js:

```
yourMomentObject.format("/[Date](xZZ)/")
```

Example:

[image: screenshot]

Without moment, you can write your own function that takes uses the `Date` object's `.getTime()` function, and `.getTimezoneOffset()` functions.  However, the offset has to be negated, then formatted properly before being added to the string.

Comment: Simple and clean, the perfect solution... Thanks